# How to iterate over all registered tasks in Gradle?

Tags: gradle

In our Gradle (using Gradle 6.4.1) project, [Configuration on demand](https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:configuration_on_demand) is enabled. It means that tasks are not configured during project's [Configuration Phase](https://docs.gradle.org/6.4.1/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases). This means, for example, that a statement `println(project.tasks)` in `subproject/build.gradle` may print only some of the tasks, which exist in the subproject.

I want to programmatically find all tasks by name in all projects. My current code just iterates over `allprojects`:

```
def foobar(Project rootProject, String name) {
    Collection<String> paths = rootProject.allprojects.findResults { Project p ->
        return p.tasks.findByName(name)?.getPath()
    }
    return paths
}
```

Method `foobar()` is called by a custom Gradle plugin to set up a complex graph of dependencies. This graph includes: "`taskFoobar` should `dependOn` on all tasks named `name` in `allprojects`". This is needed for the plugin to behave similarly to how [CLI of Gradle itself behaves](https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#executing_tasks_in_multi_project_builds):

> You can also run a task for *all* subprojects by using a task selector that consists of the task name only. For example, this will run the "test" task for all subprojects when invoked from the root project directory:
>
> ```
> $ gradle test
> ```

That's why such programmatic iteration is needed. Note, that `foobar()` is called in `rootProject.afterEvaluate` block.

However, because of the configuration-on-demand feature, some tasks in some subprojects are missing in the collection `paths`, because they weren't yet "configured", only "registered".

During investigation, I looked into how builtin task `tasks` works. Class [`TaskReportTask`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/7acee845886fee255ec8f8a488e50e11f8c0e558/subprojects/diagnostics/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/diagnostics/TaskReportTask.java#L131) uses internal Gradle API, called `ProjectTaskLister`, implementation of which [`DefaultProjectTaskLister`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/a138710ab109e271b17ee48dc49b359284cd3f66/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/project/DefaultProjectTaskLister.java), calls another internal API, namely method `realize()` of interface [`TaskContainerInternal`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/affd16faec5254d8296b8c37e15497c6d7c5c3fa/subprojects/core/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/TaskContainerInternal.java):

```
/**
 * Force the task graph to come into existence.
 */
void realize();
```

How to ensure all "registered" tasks can be iterated over without using this internal Gradle API?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Why do you want all of the task names?

Comment: @lance-java I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **don't need** to set up new dependencies you can just use `rootProject.getGradle().projectsEvaluated()` instead. This will ensure that all projects were evaluated when `foobar()` is called, not just the `rootProject`.

> Method foobar() is called by a custom Gradle plugin to set up a complex graph of dependencies.

If you **do need** to change the graph of dependencies after all projects have been evaluated, you unfortunately can't use
`rootProject.getGradle().projectsEvaluated()`. This hook is executed too late into the lifecycle of the build—all dependencies are fixed at that point.

You can, however, roll your own listener like this:

```
static void whenAllProjectsEvaluated(Project rootProject, Closure action) {
    final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger()
    final int allProjectsCount = rootProject.getAllprojects().size()
    rootProject.allprojects { p ->
        p.afterEvaluate {
            final int currentEvaluatedCount = counter.incrementAndGet()
            rootProject.logger.lifecycle("${p.name} - afterEvaluate (${currentEvaluatedCount}/$allProjectsCount")
            if (currentEvaluatedCount == allProjectsCount) {
                action.call()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`AtomicInteger` is needed to allow parallel builds. This method can then be called as:

```
whenAllProjectsEvaluated(project) {
    foobar(...)
}
```